# How to set environment variables in .xsh file?

Tags: shell, xonsh

I want to override environment variables in my `foo.xsh` file like this

```
$FOO = "foo"
```

But after I call `xonsh foo.xsh`, `$FOO` is not set.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running `xonsh foo.xsh` sets `$FOO` in a separate session that closes when the program`foo.xsh` terminates.

If you want to persist the contents of `foo.xsh` in your current session, you can use `source foo.xsh`.